# iOS Development - How to post nested values to php server side

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c, post

In my iOS application (using objective-c) I send some values to my php server and write them to my mysql database tables. Until now I needed to pass at most 2 values. My post string was always like `@"username=%@&password=%@"`. I do not have any problem with that.

However, I have to send more than 2 values now and they will be more than one. For example, I want to send something like

```
        array_A: [value1, value2, value3, value4],
        array_B: [value1, value2, value3, value4],
        array_C: [value1, value2, value3, value4]
```

How can I do that? And how can I parse it at the php side? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I would suggest trying to send the data in a json encoded format,  which is very easy in php and all other languages I know (I don't know objective c though,  but I'm sure you can take a look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you used REST with GET to deliver the values, but you can also use POST. Your iOS network library should allow this or just google for AFNetwork and look for posting. If you don't like AFNetwork search for AFNetwork alternatives. You will just set the values like a dictionary and you can set multiple values for keys.

I assume your PHP script currently is retrieving the values with $_GET['username'] and the same for password. If you 'post' your values you do just the same but instead of $_GET you use $_POST['param-name'].

Alternatively to set just one key and value have a look for JSON. Please google how to create a JSON-Document of your instances and how to set it as post value. You then have to google how to parse a JSON document in PHP. This seems for me the most simplest and cleanest solution for your problem.